# Assign control-slash to undo in Terminal.app

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, shell

I'd like to have the standard Emacs key binding <kbd>\C-/</kbd> for undo in zsh as well. However on Mac using Terminal.app, this keybinding doesn't seem to be transmitted. It will just beep, and `cat`/`read` doesn't translate it to a escape sequence.

In Preferences/Keyboards you can add sequences, but the list is fixed and you can't select <kbd>\C-/</kbd> (and <kbd>\C-;</kbd>, <kbd>\C-,</kbd> etc. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I switched to iterm2 where it works.

Comment: Please make sure to mark your answer as the accepted answer once enough time has passed to do so. If you have any other information about how you solved the problem, please do [edit] this answer! Thanks.